# SQL Server Table Calculations to Special Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
+----------+---------------+--------+
|   Year   |   Cases       | Closed |
+----------+---------------+--------+
| 2016     | 250           |   0    |  
| 2017     | 350           |   370  | 
| 2018     | 330           |   490  |  
| 2019     | 60            |   50   |
+----------+---------------+--------+
```

i need to add column "State" with formula: State = "State@Year before + Cases@this Year - Closed@this Year"

```
// 0+250-0 = 250
// 250+350-370 = 230
// 230+330-490 = 70
// 70+60-50 = 80
```

Result:

```
+----------+---------------+--------+-----------+
|   Year   |   Cases       | Closed |   State   |
+----------+---------------+--------+-----------+
| 2016     | 250           |    0   |    250    |
| 2017     | 350           |    370 |    230    |
| 2018     | 330           |    490 |    70     |
| 2019     | 60            |    50  |    80     |
+----------+---------------+--------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Use cumulative sums:

```
select t.*,
       sum(cases - closed) over (order by year) as state
from t;
```

I find `state` to be a curious name for a cumulative sum.

Answer (score 1):

You want window function :

```
select t.*,
       sum(cases - closed) over (order by year) as state
from table t;
```

**EDIT :** For older version you can use `apply` :

```
select t.*, t1.state
from table t cross apply 
     (select sum(t1.cases - t1.closed) as state
      from table t1
      where t1.yr <= t.yr
     ) t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple to do that try the below code:

```
select *,
       sum(cases - closed) over (order by year) as [state]
from StackOverFlow_4
```